# DragSelectionUpdateCallback Flutter Error

Tags: android, windows, flutter

```
C:\Users\ptl\Documents\App Dev\ChurchApp_Flutter>flutter build apk --no-shrink

../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_quill-6.1.6/lib/src/widgets/text_selection.dart:772:9: Error: Type 'DragSelectionUpdateCallback' not found.
  final DragSelectionUpdateCallback? onDragSelectionUpdate;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Am getting this error, i tried to installed and uninstalled flutter as i someone said that worked for him but i am still getting the same issue. I am using the latest version of flutter as of when getting this error that's version 3.10.5. i get the error when i try to build apk i have tried to the best of my knowledge as nothing has worked for me searched google and not getting any similar error anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the library that appears on your screen

Comment: Kindy see the image from the link below, if i need to install libraries as you stated
https://pasteboard.co/g3W6ywdLusrE.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not with flutter but with your code.
`DragSelectionUpdateCallback` has been removed in flutter version 3.10
you have to use `TextSelectionGestureDetector` instead.